# Jquery Sortables - existem diferentes formas de mover um compomente como por uma imagem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

No exemplo original o usuário pode clicar em qualquer parte do < div conteudo >  (ou compomente) e move-lo,

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/:

```
<div id="sortable" >
   <div> conteudo 1 </div>
   <div> conteudo 2 </div>
   <div> conteudo 3 </div>
   <div> conteudo 4 </div>
</div >
```

Mas eu gostaria de ter apenas um botão pequeno (imagem por exemplo), e somente ele ser "clicável" e assim movimentar o componente, por exemplo

```
<div id="sortable" >
   <div> <img src=move.gif> conteudo  </div>
   <div> <img src=move.gif> conteudo  </div>
   <div> <img src=move.gif> conteudo  </div>
   <div> <img src=move.gif> conteudo  </div>
</div >
```

isso eh possível? alguém tem um exemplo?

obrigado!

Comment: Não percebi bem o que que fazer. Quer que só um dos elementos é que dê para fazer o `drag & drop`?

Comment: editei a pergunta! espero ter ficado mais legivel...